# Problems to register a knockout component before viewModel

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm tryng to register my login modal knockout component but the top view is beeing created before my component has been register.

I'm using requireJs to organize my js files.

this is the view

```
<div data-bind='component: componentModal'></div>
```

this is where I register

`require(['modals/login']);` - Inside this, there is:

```
require(['jquery', 'knockout', 'text!modals/login.html', 'bootstrap'], function ($, ko, htmlString) {

    ko.components.register('login-modal', {
        viewModel: function (params) {
            console.log(params);
            this.text = ko.observable(params && params.initialText || '');
        },
        template: htmlString
    });
});
```

And then in my main js file, I have:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
<script>

    require(['main'], function () {

        require(['modals/login']);

        require(['knockout'], function (ko) {

            var ViewModel = function () {
                var self = this;
                self.componentModal = ko.observable('login-modal');

                return self;
            };

            ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());


        });

    });
</script>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding this line:

```
self.componentModal = ko.observable('login-modal');
```

Creating an observable with the string 'login-modal' does nothing.  It just is an observable with the string login modal.  It doesn't magically include your modal component.

Your html needs to have your custom `<login-modal></login-modal>` html element or even `<div data-bind="component: {name: 'login-modal', params: {your: params}"></div>` should work

Your requirejs code in your <script> tag is wrong.  I think it should be:

```
require(['main', 'modals/login', 'knockout'], function(main, login, ko) {
// ... your code here
});
```